# How to install Ubuntu on a small partition with the highest security settings

Tags: partitioning, security

I want to make a fresh Ubuntu installation on my laptop. In the past I used to follow the default installation instructions by creating a single partition and then enabling passphrase and encrypting the whole disk. However, this time I would like to create two partitions; a small one for all programs, settings etc. (so as to create a relative small clone image later on) and a second one for my documents. In addition, I would like to have both partitions encrypted and as secure as possible. But as an amateur Ubuntu user I am a bit afraid of the settings I should choose. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full disk encryption - separate home partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233077/full-disk-encryption-separate-home-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: [Privacy in Ubuntu 12.10: Full Disk Encryption](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/11/privacy-ubuntu-1210-full-disk-encryption)